# How to format vue file using html-beautify & standard in vim?

Tags: vim, format, vue.js

I'm learning vuejs. I use vim as my editor.

I want to format the template section of a vue component using html-beautify, and format the script section using standard and css with css-beautify.

I'm not sure how can I do this? Any suggestion or recommended format program?

Comment: Try `:help filter`

Answer (score 1):

You could visual select your desired lines using linewise visual mode `V` and run your beautifier on them; for example locate your cursor between `<script></script>` tag and type: `Vit` then type `:`(this will also insert `'<,'>` which means visual selected lines) then run the system command `js-beautify` on selected lines using `!` operator:

```
:'<,'>!js-beautify
```

for css and html also select their regions and run `html-beautify` or `css-beautify`

Also check this another answer of mine on how to treat each section separately: [change-the-filetype-based-on-tags-regions-in-the-file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10802/7976)